# python для embedded linux

Tags: python, arm, linux

Ищу сабж, пока ничего достойного не нашел...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что значит достойного? О чём идёт речь? Просто берёте и собираете его и будет работать. Я сам собирал пару лет назад сабж с помощью open embedded. Сборка получилась вполне рабочая.

Comment: Достойный, значит работает, ничего полностью написанного на си не нашел...

Comment: При чём тут С? Речь об обычном питоне, который собирается и работает. Сформулируйте пожалуйста, что конкретно вы хотите.

Comment: "ничего полностью написанного на си не нашел"? правильно говорит cy6erGn0m - "Речь об обычном питоне, который собирается и работает". Референсная имплементация (ой!) - написана на Си и собирается для большинства платформ с gcc без особых проблем. Успехов!